# awk to store field length in variable then use in print

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to store the length of `$5` in a variable `il` if the condition is met (in the two lines it is) and then add that variable to `$3` in the `print` statement. The two `sub` statements are to remove the matching from both `$5` and `$6`. The script as is executes and produces the current output. However, `il` does not seem to be populated and added in the `print`. It seems close but I'm not sure why the variable isn't being stored?  Thank you :)

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}  # define fs and output
   FNR==NR{ # process each field in each line of file
     if(length($5) < length($6)) {  # condition
      il=$(length($5))
       echo $il
        sub($5,"",$6) && sub($6,"",$5)       # removing matching
         print $1,$2,$3+$il,$3+$il,"-",$6  # print desired output
           next
}
}' in
```

**in**  `tab-delimited`

```
id1 1   116268178       GAAA    GAAAA
id2 2   228197304       A   AATCC
```

**current output**  `tab-delimited`

```
id1 1   116268178   116268178   -   A
id2 2   228197304   228197304   -   ATCC
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`

```
since `$5` is 4 in line 1 that is added to `$3`
since `$5` is 1 in line 2 that is added to `$3`

id1 1   116268181   116268181   -   A
id2 2   228197305   228197305   -   ATCC
```

Comment: You are mixing up shell script and awk, for example `il=$(length($5))` should probably be `il=$length($5)`, original form would place the length _th_ column to `il`. Also, no `echo` in awk, use `print`. Might be something else too, didn't check any further (well, those `sub`s at least).

Comment: In the original `in` `$4` is null and gets filled in in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your comments they helped solve it, if you add them as an answer I will accept :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{$3+=length($4);$3=$3 OFS $3;sub($4,"",$5);$4="-"} 1' Input_file
```

Please add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and you require output in TAB delimited form too.